# cone structure of complement of hyperplanes

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, extremal-combinatorics, hyperplane-arrangements, cones

I want to know if in $\mathbb{R}^{m+3}$ we consider the following hyperplanes:

\begin{cases}
     (1-g)y-\sum_{i\in I}x_i=0, & \text{if $I\subset\{1,\cdots,m+2\}$},|I|=g\\
    gy-\sum_{i\in I}x_i+\sum_{i=1}^{m+2}x_i=0       & \text{if $I\subset\{1,\cdots,m+2\}$,|I|=g+1}
\end{cases}
$ $ where $y, x_1,\cdots, x_{m+2}$ are coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^{m+3}$, $g$, $m$ are integers greater than $1$ and take complement in $\mathbb{R}^{m+3}$.Is the complement has a cone structure? i.e. I want to know is the complement can be written as union of cones in $\mathbb{R}^{m+3}$? If so what are the generators?

Comment: Yes, the complement of any arrangement of central hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a union of open polyhedral cones. Another way of looking at it is that the hyperplanes define a complete polyhedral fan.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. can you give me some reference where some calculations have been done about hyperplane complement?@ Sam Hopkins

Comment: I'm not sure I have a good source for computations, but I can say a little more. Associated to your hyperplane arrangement is a certain convex polyhedron called a zonotope, which is a Minkowski sum of line segments. Specifically, the hyperplane arrangement gives the normal fan of the zonotope. If you are interested in the rays of this fan, then what you want to compute are the vertices of the (polar) dual to this zonotope.

Comment: Thanks again@Sam Hopkins